# Detect footnote markers inside strings using regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm using regex to detect footnote markers and then format them into superscripts in Android. This ini my code:

```
public static SpannedString formatFootnotes(String text) {
    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text);

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\)");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        sp.setSpan(SUPERSCRIPT, m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sp.setSpan(SIZE, m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    return new SpannedString(sp);
}
```

The code above works fine most of time. However it sometimes fails when the footnote appear after punctuations (comma, period) i.e.

> this is some text,15)

I have no problem when the numbers appear after alphanumerics. What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: It has not got anything to do with a comma. Most probably, there is some other code that interferes with the one you posted.

Comment: I've solved the problem. You're correct that it has nothing to do with regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is setSpan() only work when the first arg is not reused. So the solution would be creating SuperscriptSpan and RelativeSizeSpan objects inside the loop:

```
public static SpannedString formatFootnotes(String text) {
    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text);

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\)");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        sp.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sp.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    return new SpannedString(sp);
}
```